# except vs. aside from

Tags: prepositions

*1. Has this sequence any aesthetic or stylistic purpose except shocking the audience?*

*2. Has this sequence any aesthetic or stylistic purpose aside from shocking the audience?*

The first sentence is mine and was modified by the native speaker into the second one. What was wrong with my original?

Comment: There's nothing unnatural about it, but it isn't conversational, for sure. Inverting "have" when it isn't the auxiliary of another verb is British and archaic. The rest is fine. For "except" vs. "aside from", I'd prefer "aside from" too, but not for any obvious reason. I don't think I would be tempted to correct it on the fly.

Comment: My internal style guide says "any purpose except to shock", "any purpose other than to shock", "any purpose aside from shocking".

Comment: So it is not possible to use "except" before participle/gerund?

Comment: That is too broad a statement, I think, @bart-leby.  The word **purpose** is implicated here.  *He had no circus experience except sweeping up the elephant manure.*  That's fairly colloquial, and maybe marginal to some ears, but I think it's legit.

Comment: Maybe I am both British and archaic but I see absolutely nothing wrong with your original version or, indeed, with the supposed correction. (Supposed because there was nothing that needed correcting)

Comment: Quite possibly personal preference. To me, the first sentence does sound slightly off, but I couldn't tell you why. Interesting experiment: take a survey of native speakers, without telling them which one you came up with and which one you didn't, and ask them which one they prefer. Also randomize the order in which they appear.

Answer (score 1):

> Has this sequence any aesthetic or stylistic purpose **except to shock** the audience?

is slightly more correct than "shocking", although all three sentences are valid. *"Aside from" is always followed by a gerund, and "except" should be followed by an infinitive.*